# Add transform: skew to container only, not text within

Tags: css, shapes

Is there a way to transform an element but not the text inside that element?

```
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 100px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

div {
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-radius */
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* box-shadow */
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0px 1px 3px;
   -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

(code - http://cssdesk.com/H7Awc)

I've several ways including adding the before pseudo class to it, which works in theory but I'm adding this navigation to a wordpress site and the a's can't have position:absolute. Here is the code using the before pseudo which is how I need it to look but without the absolute

http://cssdesk.com/ALRrQ

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I see you tried to reset the skewing for the text by adding `skew(20deg)` to that span.
But `transform` does not apply to inline elements as span is.

**Solution**

```
span {
    display:inline-block; /*important line*/
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
       -moz-transform: skew(20deg);
         -o-transform: skew(20deg);
}
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Whre/PsVfr/)

Comment: Thanks so much for that! I got it working awesomely. But now the skew has effected the dropdown on Products. If I remove the skew, it works okay. Can you help? http://www.fi-testing.co.uk/birchfield/

Comment: Create an extra rule for the transform stuff: `nav.top-bar #menu-topmenu>li.menu-item`. That should work since > will only affect the direct children of the top menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same skew to the text only with a negative value.

so the div would be skew(-20deg);
and the text within it would be skew(20deg);